# Scala split and line start in the regex

Tags: regex, scala, split

I am trying to split the string in to four parts P, Q, R, S.

String starts with P as per the following example :

```
"P|VAL1|VAL2|VAL3|BLANK|Q|VAL4|BLANK|BLANK|R|VAL5|BLANK|VAL6|HELP|BLANK|VAL7|S|EDIT|BLANK|VAL8|(SDK 1.8)|BLANK".split("[(^?P\\|)][(Q?\\|)]?[(R?\\|)]?[(S?\\|)]")
```

"P|VAL1|VAL2|VAL3|BLANK|Q|VAL4|BLANK|BLANK|R|VAL5|BLANK|VAL6|HELP|BLANK|VAL7|S|EDIT|BLANK|VAL8|(SDK 1.8)|BLANK".split("[(^?P\|)][(Q?\|)]?[(R?\|)]?[(S?\|)]") foreach println

gives

```
VAL1|VAL2|VAL3|BLANK
VAL4|BLANK|BLANK
VAL5|BLANK|VAL6|HEL
BLANK|VAL7
|EDIT|BLANK|VAL8
DK 1.8
BLANK
```

where my expectation is :

```
VAL1|VAL2|VAL3|BLANK
VAL4|BLANK|BLANK
VAL5|BLANK|VAL6|HELP|BLANK|VAL7
EDIT|BLANK|VAL8|(SDK 1.8)|BLANK
```

However

`"P|VAL1|VAL2|VAL3|BLANK|Q|VAL4|BLANK|BLANK|R|VAL5|BLANK|VAL6|HELP|BLANK|VAL7|S|EDIT|BLANK|VAL8|(SDK 1.8)|BLANK".split("[(^P\\|)][(Q?\\|)]?[(R?\\|)]?[(S?\\|)]") (0)`

Checking first element of split with above gives

```
res9: String = ""
```

It seems that start of string is not honored here. I tried this on [regex 101](https://regex101.com/) as well it correctly matches P| at the start. However it also matches `P|` in the `|HELP|`. So it seems my regex is flawed. However my question is How the empty string above comes in to play ?

Comment: Look at the explanation on regex101. You thought that `^` would indicate beginning of line, but it does not when placed inside a character class.

Comment: Do you know that your current split gives an array that starts with an empty string? (first element)

Comment: @nhahtdh that's exactly what I thought. Just checked this on Java as well, it's the same result.

Comment: @allan yes I know that.

Comment: Ok, than you can directly use my 1st regex it should work! ;-)

Comment: @allan Yes indeed, :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex if having an empty first element of your list is not important:

```
\\|[QRS]\\||^P\\|
```

You can replace this regex by `\\|[PQRS]\\||^P\\|` if you except other `P` as separator inside the string

**OUTPUT:**

```
"P|VAL1|VAL2|VAL3|BLANK|Q|VAL4|BLANK|BLANK|R|VAL5|BLANK|VAL6|HELP|BLANK|VAL7|S|EDIT|BLANK|VAL8|(SDK 1.8)|BLANK".split("\\|[QRS]\\||^P\\|");

[, VAL1|VAL2|VAL3|BLANK, VAL4|BLANK|BLANK, VAL5|BLANK|VAL6|HELP|BLANK|VAL7, EDIT|BLANK|VAL8|(SDK 1.8)|BLANK]
```

Otherwise you need to do it in 2 steps:

- match and remove the `P|` at the beginning of your string using `^P\\|` and replacing it by nothing [**demo1**](https://regex101.com/r/MgXvCG/1)
- split the string using the regex `\\|[QRS]\\|` [**demo2**](https://regex101.com/r/MgXvCG/2/) You can replace this regex by `\\|[PQRS]\\|` if you except other `P` as separator inside the string

Comment: I could live with empty first element at start. So first approach seems to be do the trick for me and the regex is nice on eye as well. Performance wise first approach is superior to my understanding as I am doing this against a file with around million of records.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach that defines the delimiter as one of `P, Q, R, S` enclosed by word boundary `\b` and optional `|`:

```
val s = "P|VAL1|VAL2|VAL3|BLANK|Q|VAL4|BLANK|BLANK|R|VAL5|BLANK|VAL6|HELP|BLANK|VAL7|S|EDIT|BLANK|VAL8|(SDK 1.8)|BLANK"

s.split("""\|?\b[PQRS]\b\|?""").filter(_ != "")
// res1: Array[String] = Array(VAL1|VAL2|VAL3|BLANK, VAL4|BLANK|BLANK, VAL5|BLANK|VAL6|HELP|BLANK|VAL7, EDIT|BLANK|VAL8|(SDK 1.8)|BLANK)
```

Skip the `filter` in case you want to include extracted empty strings.